# .net core Redirecting to Route Results adds %2f to url

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

This is my routing item:

```
context.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new {area="Identity", controller = "Account / Login", action = "Index" }));
```

When the application starts, this is what I get in the url:

> http://localhost:62527/Identity/Account%2FLogin

How can I remove the %2f from my url?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `controller = "Account / Login"` ?

Comment: @AntP My Login was scaffolded by Identity. So it is in a folder called Account

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When attempting to generate a URL from your `RouteValueDictionary`, ASP.NET Core encodes the `/` as `%2F` simply because it's part of a [URL segment](https://processwire.com/docs/tutorials/how-to-use-url-segments/) and has special meaning (it's the segment delimiter).

`Account/Login` is *invalid* as a controller name in this context, simply because `/` is not valid as part of a C# identifier (i.e. `Accounts/LoginController` is invalid as a class name).

As you're attempting to route to `Account/Login` in the `Identity` area, I'm going to assume for now that you're using ASP.NET Core Identity's Default UI and that you're intention is to route to the `/Account/Login` *Razor Page* in the default `Identity` area. In order to do that, there's at least a couple of options:

1. Set the `page` route-value rather than the `controller` route-value:

   ```
   context.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
       new RouteValueDictionary(new { area = "Identity", page = "/Account/Login" }));
   ```
2. Use `RedirectToPageResult` instead of `RedirectToRouteResult`:

   ```
   context.Result = new RedirectToPageResult("/Account/Login", new { area = "Identity" });
   ```

I recommend using the `RedirectToPageResult` option here, as it has a clearer intent that this is directed towards a Razor Page rather than an MVC Controller.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **UrlDecode**(your url string )  of **HttpServerUtility** before redirecting.